# Is there a utility for polymorphic object creation somewhere in the standard library

Tags: scala, implicit

I often write this utility in my projects:

```
def instance[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) =
    m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
```

It looks like something that could well be in the standard library, but I have not been able to find it. Did I miss it? If not could the powers that be add it :)

EDIT

If runtime exceptions when T lacks a no-arg constructor are unacceptable one can define

```
def maybeInstance[T:Manifest] = try Some(instance[T]) catch {case _ => None}
```

possibly making the underlying `instance` function private.
However, many standard functions throw runtime exceptions,
including division & many networking operation.

Comment: I don't know. As far as I'm concerned I try to avoid manifests. Can you elaborate on what you use `instance` for?

Comment: There is no point in such a method, cause you can't instantiate type constructors like `List[Int]` and mixin composition would be a problem

Comment: Obviously, to instanciate objects of `T` in generic contexts (where `T` cannot be fully known at compile time at the point of instanciation). @Daniel Mahler: The main problem is that `instance` will fail at runtime if the class has no no-arg constructor or is abstract, or is an interface, or any other type that is not a class, such as `Int with String`, and so on. This can be fine in controlled situations where, but this is not good for a general prupose method of the standard library.

Comment: I know it only works for concrete classes with no-arg constructors, but this is still a very common and useful pattern, often recommended for polymorphic creation. There are even several questions on it here on SO. If there was a way to use structural types to say that a class has a no-arg constructor, the it could be used to constraint T to cases where this is valid, but a quick search suggests this is not possible. Is it?